# Error in Recursion

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion, primes

```
import sys,math

def Check_Prime(n) :
    if n%2 and n<3 :
        return False
    else :
        return all(n%p for p in range(3,int(math.sqrt(n))+1,2))

def Reduce(n) :
    if Check_Prime(n) :
        Reduce(n-1)
    else :
        return n

def main(*args,**kwargs) :
    for __ in range(input()) :
        l,b=map(int,sys.stdin.readline().split(' '))
        l=Reduce(l)
        b=Reduce(b)
        print l*b

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    main()
```

It's not returning once the condition in `Reduce()` function fails.

I have tried to `print` the value of `n` inside the `else` block and it successfully printed it, but it is failing to return that value inside the `else` block.

Comment: Indentation is import in Python; without the formatting, we can't tell what's wrong. Please [**read the editing help**](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). You should also consider reading [the style guide](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: The indentation was actually there, it was just not placed in a code block, so StackOverflow did not display it. I did not guess anything.

Comment: @jonrsharpe i just edited my post...it's indented now...

Comment: Please see *every other recursion question* - you don't `return` the value from the recursive call.

Comment: @DanielDarabos it's indented now to fit stackoverflow to show how the code originally looks...

Answer (score 1):

Your function `Reduce()` is not returning anything when it recurses. You'd want to change

```
def Reduce(n) :
    if Check_Prime(n) :
        Reduce(n-1)
    else :
        return n
```

into

```
def Reduce(n) :
    if Check_Prime(n) :
        return Reduce(n-1)
    else :
        return n
```

That way, each code path in Reduce returns a value.

Comment: Yeah thanks...and could you pls provide me some links about how to post the codes in stakoverflow....

Comment: @pvkcse Generally, you want to prepend four spaces in front of your code in a post. See [StackOverflow's docs](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more info.

Comment: Now i got it...Thanks @Arda Xi